# Brilliant Gallery: where to put [bg|...] tags?

Tags: drupal

I want to use the Brilliant Gallery (Drupal) to show a public Picasa album.
According to the documentation (http://vacilando.net/bg), the RSS feed of your album should be a tag:

> Then, in your your web version of the
>   album, right click & copy its "RSS"
>   link, and simply use that link instead
>   of the local path in the [bg|path] tag
>   ... e.g.
>   [bg|http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/tjfulopp/albumid/5290148828710951169?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=en_US].

My question: I dont have a clue where I can paste this RSS feed; and where to put this [bg...] tag.
I went to the brlliant_gallery/settings cannot find anything like fill your tag here.
Created a node and put [bg|..] etc in, did not work.

Where to put the [bg|..] tag?

**UPDATE**
I've given up on this Brilliant Gallery, I cannot get it to work. If you just want to use picasa with lightbox2, I suggest to use the photopic module at http://www.kevincarbonaro.com/book/photopic-drupal-module. Works like a charm.

It is not available in the official Drupal Modules at drupal.org, because they say that the BG already has this functionality.
Well they are right, but this is simple and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely skipped over the step where you need to set up the brilliant gallery filter on an input format. This makes it so Drupal will use Brilliant Gallery to process the [bg|..] tag when you place it in a node.

Make sure you have enabled the Module in Site Building -> Modules. Then, go to Site Configuration -> Input Formats (or http://yoursite.com/admin/settings/filters ) and via the "configure" link enable one of your input formats to recognize the Brilliant Gallery Tag. I'd suggest doing this on "Filtered HTML" and then when you create your node, make sure the input format for it is set to "Filtered HTML.

Create a node just as you said and place the [bg|http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/tjfulopp/albumid/5290148828710951169?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=en_US] tag in it, replacing that URL with your Picasa RSS URL of course, and you should be good to go.

For further instructions, you can see the author of that module's documentation at: http://vacilando.net/bg

Comment: Thx. This step I could not find in the documentation.
I get an empty page...I created a new Input Format. Checked BG and Lightbox boxes. Created a node. Entered [bg|..] public album. Nothing on the page...

Comment: In the watchdog logs I see:
Fetched 167 images from http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/eddy147/albumid/5100310190580950593?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=nl. Elapsed time: 142 seconds.
So he fetches alright...but just does not display them

Comment: I used a clean drupal install 6.19, only BG and lightbox2 installed
in files I have bgcache directory, all 777.

Comment: I've given up in this Brilliant Gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the guy above. I would upvote but cant.
Again that step is not mentioned anywhere i could find in the documentation.
Buddy needs to write a decent document that covers things rather than just having random examples on his site